# Are Claims the best way to handle programmatic logic determining what is displayed?

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, claims-based-identity, claims

I am writing an application to manage volunteers for political campaigns. This is a lot more complicated than any past multi-tenant app I've written and so am asking for guidance here to if claims are the best way to handle this. And if so, any guidance to the implementation.

First off you have admins, managers, & volunteers. They each have different things they can see and do. But in addition, they are limited to one or a small set of campaigns. For example, the admin for a state legislative campaign in New Jersey has no access at any level to a senate race in Colorado.

While there are some web pages where you must be an admin or manager, most of the limitations, including the admin only pages, limit what specifics are displayed on the page. Every manager can go to the "create a volunteer event" page. But they are all limited to only seeing existing and creating new events for the campaign they manage.

Oh, and some user will be an admin and/or manager for several campaigns. And most volunteers will be a volunteer on several campaigns.

So...

1. Are claims the way to go on this?
2. And to implement this, I have the ASP.NET Core Identity incorporated into my system with  Identification(login) working. So I would use the claims part of this - correct?
3. Do I then create for each user a bunch of claims like Claim(admin, "Dave for Pres")?
4. Do I then write my queries to FindAll(ev => ev.Campaign.Name == claim.name) to populate the existing events?
5. This means I'm creating all these claims as people get/lose rights and map them to the campaigns. So I need to keep them in sync.

   1. And no need to create a claim that would be given to every user. For that, just require an authenticated user - correct?
6. Am I missing anything?

The alternative is each campaign object has a collection of admins, managers, and volunteers. (Not asking which is better, just what are additional trade-offs.)

- Advantage - the "claim" is a part of the campaign object and so no need to sync.
- Disadvantage - the "claim" has moved for the Identity system to a business object.
- Disadvantage - have to write a bunch of code that already exists in the Identity library.
- Any other advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: I'm pretty sure multiple claims is not the way to go [especially based on your other question that I answered] as there are likely to be a lot of claims associated with a user.  So can a user be a Manager of one campaign, a Volunteer in another campaign and a Admin in several others?  Is this a matrix?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis short answer - yes. In practice though most will have a single claim. And it’s unlikely  many will have more than 2 - 3. Political campaign organization is incredibly decentralized.